# How to get Google refresh token with knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle?

Tags: symfony, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, refresh-token

I use `knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle` and `league/oauth2-google` to connect users in my Symfony 4 web app using a "Sign in with Google" feature.  I followed [this](https://hugo-soltys.com/blog/easily-implement-google-login-with-symfony-4) tuto. I registered my app in Google.

I set `access_type: offline` in the `knpu.oauth2.client.google` configuration (`config/packages/knpu_oauth2_client.yaml` file)

I try to get the user refresh token in my `GoogleAuthenticator::getUser(League\OAuth2\Client\Token\AccessToken $credentials)` method (which extends `KnpU\OAuth2ClientBundle\Security\Authenticator\SocialAuthenticator`).

Unfortunately, `$credentials->getRefreshToken()` always returns `null`.

Why don't I get the user refresh token ?

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-google#refreshing-a-token), "Refresh tokens are only provided to applications which request offline access". So, when instantiating the provider you need to set the accessType.

```
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google;

$provider = new Google([
    'clientId'     => '{google-client-id}',
    'clientSecret' => '{google-client-secret}',
    'redirectUri'  => 'https://example.com/callback-url',
    'accessType'   => 'offline',
]);
```

In knpu_oauth2_client [configuration](https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle#configuration), you can do:

```
google:
    type: google
    client_id: '%env(OAUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)%'
    client_secret: '%env(OAUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET)%'
    redirect_params: {}
    access_type: offline
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Had to do 2 things to solve this:

1.) add prompt => consent to force new consent, otherwise the offline-access-type will not be changed, if wasn't configured in the beginning

```
return $clientRegistry
  ->getClient('google') // key used in config/packages/knpu_oauth2_client.yaml
  ->redirect([
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly'
  ], 
      [
         'prompt' => 'consent',
        'access_type' => 'offline',
      ]
    );
```

2.) this is NOT working:

```
$accessToken = $client->getAccessToken()->getToken();
$refreshToken = $client->getAccessToken()->getRefreshToken();
```

Instead to this:

```
$tokens = $client->getAccessToken();
$accessToken = $tokens->getToken();
$refreshToken = $tokens->getRefreshToken();
```